# Unable to the delete or rename the title name of the chart through VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I'am a learner in Excel vba programming.

I have a written a code to create a chart in excel VBA which creates successfully.
But, the title name of the chart is created only once, unable to delete or change the title name in the chart.
The code will stop in debug mode at

```
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Delete
```

Hence, require your assistance in the below code

```
Sub chart()
Dim chtquarters As ChartObject
Set chtquarters = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=240, Width:=360, Top:=50, Height:=288)

chtquarters.chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A3:B7")
chtquarters.chart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate


ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Delete

With ActiveChart.Legend

   .LegendEntries(1).LegendKey.Interior.Color = vbYellow
   .LegendEntries(2).LegendKey.Interior.Color = vbCyan
   .LegendEntries(3).LegendKey.Interior.Color = vbRed
   .LegendEntries(4).LegendKey.Interior.Color = vbGreen  


ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)

ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Quarterly Sales"


ActiveChart.Legend.Select


With Selection.Font
  .Name = "Arial"
  .FontStyle = "Bold"
  .Size = "14"

Range("A1").Select

End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In your code you are trying to delee a chart title before you have actually given the chart a title (i.e. "Quarterly Sales").

Comment: read this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e912389-f86c-449b-a359-c033e182bc26/setting-chart-title-through-vba-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt

Comment: Hi Alex P and Mark thanks for reading my post, I will clear your doubts on my post.I'am trying to create a Pie chart the code is linked with a button and once clicked it will show the chart title name "Quarterly Sales" mentioned in the code with the Pie chart, but if I again click the button it will not change the name of the title to "quarterly sales" instead it will give the name defined for the Sales numbers for showing the sales figures in the chart, please give your advise on this issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have deleted the chart title, set the `HasTitle` property of the chart to True before assigning the new text, as in

```
With Worksheets("sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart
   .HasTitle = True
   .ChartTitle.Text = "February Sales"
End With
```

Comment: I Just added the code    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete which will delete the chartobject and replace new chart..hence solved my issue, many thanks for all your suggestions and advise :-)